# TypeScript failing to correctly infer types from generic using keyof as property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm currently writing some typedefs and classes for a validation component, which is being constructed to validate fields on a specific class ('Main' below). The objective:

1. Each validation rule (`MainValidationRule`) should contain the key (`T extends keyof Main`) that it's validating, as well as a validation function that validates the corresponding value and returns a flag indicating validity (`(value: Main[T]) => boolean`).
2. For ease of working with the validator, at runtime the array of validation rules will be assembled into an object mapping each field (`T in keyof Main`) to an array of all the validation rules for that field (`Array<MainValidationRule<T>>`).

However, when I try to map the rules into the desired structured (code below), TypeScript gives a type error:

[Image of type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUD0H.png)

I would have assumed that, because any given value of `rule.key` guarantees that `rule` will satisfy the constraints (ie. we know that if `rule.key === 'foo'`, then `rule` will satisfy the type `MainValidationRule<'foo'>`, and the same is true of 'bar' or any other key that might be added to `Main`), this would compile fine. But instead TypeScript seems to be checking whether *all* possible values for `MainValidationRule<keyof Main>` are valid rules for a *specific* key, which fails as (for example) `MainValidationRule<'bar'>` isn't a valid rule if the key is `'foo'` - despite the fact our constraints mean that will never be possible.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there another way I can write this that would lead TypeScript to correctly infer that the constraint is satisfied? The `Main` class is updated frequently with new properties, so manually typing out and checking every possible variation is impractical. Code below. Thanks in advance!

```
type Main = {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
};

type MainValidationRule<T extends keyof Main> = {
    key: T;
    isValid: (value: Main[T]) => boolean;
};

type MainValidationRulesMap = { [ T in keyof Main ]?: Array<MainValidationRule<T>> };
const mainValidationRulesMap: MainValidationRulesMap = {};
const mainValidationRules: Array<MainValidationRule<keyof Main>> = [];

mainValidationRules.forEach(rule => {
    mainValidationRulesMap[rule.key] = [ rule ]; // type error
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Some time it is bette to use union type instead of `Foo<keyof Bar>`

To make it clear, just compare my `MainValidationRule` and `MainValidationRule<keyof Main>`.

It seams that they are equal, but it is not true.

For TS it is much easier to infer simple union type.

Here is the code:

```js
type Main = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
};

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type MainValidationRule = Values<{
  [P in keyof Main]: {
    key: P;
    isValid: (value: Main[P]) => boolean;
  }
}>

type Rules = Array<MainValidationRule>


type MainValidationRulesMap = Partial<{ [T in keyof Main]: Rules }>;

const mainValidationRulesMap: MainValidationRulesMap = {};

const mainValidationRules: Rules = [];

mainValidationRules.forEach(rule => {
  mainValidationRulesMap[rule.key] = [rule]; // ok
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgSwHZQLxQN4CgpQGYD2BAXFAM7ABOyA5gNw5QBGclpSArgLZMSUMBfBllCQoANTgAbDhDIAeACoA%20NFEUBtANYQQBPOoC6WEeGjxkkqQgAmcYAgJIAShynR0V2Quy4NABShkKB09AwskQ1JfXBDdUn8GWKCyK1tSAAoAN2lZUgiAwwBKNFUmInc4JCSoASwBZRNRaFd3MjUAQUpKOBB5CLS7BydWiEams1hEJEH7Rxc3OXgwNQwoDUUglFD9KeRDAH5SUfahEwBjJwooLmnZ4YW25fy76Vs5kcWyZdWzrEukNdbpY3kN5idjl81BpDMJgTNQR9HnIAHSESgAUTg5wAFhlKItSphGPD7uCvssNAT3CjQoZodSILCoAB6FlQZpQPiUAiUepFBhAA)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this loses type safety between the key on `MainValidationRulesMap` and the rules in the array. So, for example, this would allow for:
`const mainValidationRulesMap: MainValidationRulesMap = { foo: [ { key: 'bar', ... } ] }`. The goal is to be able to create a type-safe map at the end between the key and the validation rules for that key.

Comment: @SteveHopkinson Don't you think that `foo` property is redundant here?
I'm not sure if you need an array, since you want to allow only one object in the array. If you still want to allow only one object I will make a safe type but I don't think this is the correct way

Comment: The code above is simplified compared with the actual code - in practice there could be much larger arrays of rules which will be generated dynamically (but still throw the same type errors). I'm not sure what you mean about the foo property being redundant - the key field is necessary for filtering and mapping the rules at runtime.