# Typescript: Enforcing property type based on another property value which is a key of a generic

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Given the following type:

```
export type MyType = {
    a: boolean;
    b: number;
}
```

I want to create a type:

```
export type Mapper<T> = {
    key: keyof T;
    func: (value: string) => T[key];
}
```

So that I can have:

```
const mapToMyTypePropertyA: Mapper<MyType> = {
    key: "a",
    func: v => !!v // enforce output type to be the type of MyType["a"], which is boolean
};

const mapToMyTypePropertyA: Mapper<MyType> = {
    key: "b",
    func: v => v.length // enforce output type to be the type of MyType["b"], which is number
};
```

i.e. I want to enforce the return type of `func` (which is a function) to be the type of a property of a generic type determined by the `key` (which is a keyof the generic type).

Is this possible?

I could only get to this so far:

```
export type Mapper<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    key: K;
    func: (value: string) => T[K];
}
const mapToMyTypePropertyA: Mapper<MyType, "a"> = {
    key: "a",
    func: v => !!v // I get the enforcement here
}
```

But this requires repeating the key twice in the generic type and in the property `key`.

Comment: I believe your question is almost a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337050/typescript-failing-to-correctly-infer-types-from-generic-using-keyof-as-property#answer-67337548)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use another type to "generate" the possible objects:

```
type GenerateCombos<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        key: K;
        func: (value: string) => T[K];
    };
}[keyof T];
```

This will give us a union of the allowed objects. For example, `GenerateCombos<{ foo: string }>` would only give us:

```
{ key: "foo"; func: (value: string) => string }
```

And `GenerateCombos<MyType>` gives us the nice type:

```
{
    key: "a";
    func: (value: string) => boolean;
} | {
    key: "b";
    func: (value: string) => number;
}
```

To use it, you can give it an alias first:

```
type Mapper = GenerateCombos<MyType>;
```

Then annotate the types of variables:

```
const mapToMyTypeProperty1: Mapper = {
    key: "a",
    func: v => !!v // enforce output type to be the type of MyType["a"], which is boolean
};

const mapToMyTypeProperty2: Mapper = {
    key: "b",
    func: v => v.length // enforce output type to be the type of MyType["b"], which is number
};
```

And it also errors if you do it incorrectly:

```
const mapToMyTypeProperty3: Mapper = {
    key: "a",
    func: v => v // ! error
};

const mapToMyTypeProperty4: Mapper = {
    key: "b",
    func: v => !!v // ! error
};
```

Try this out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKuoEMAuKAIwHsyAbCfAOwG5s9TjaBXAWxIgCdGsAvtmyhIUAOIRavfMAgBhMlzIBnADzwAfFFSYceANoBpKAEtaUANYQQZAGZR4AXWJ7mzayGJH+7vHbZaAGNiAAoAN3xKNghiFWAecwBzAEodbXhjJ188AX4BA097R2zhLFFoGHwwSB4dCSkZOUVldThESE1+bCCyWnioDmr4MnakAAUeMlrQAEZiKpreerc8T2IAInwNgBomf0CQqHD0qABCM5OAeiuoKTsyHiDoMjZgMDeoCq+yUmhgAAW-yQUGKY0gBi2GycOygAHcAaYggCzCpSBRqHRsHkyr1+sBBsNRggJlMZiAAEwLaq1Fb7XDrKAbEi7elQALBYgnZDacIAOmotCSgKgNzutAeTxebw+BO+wF+3C+QK+ILBJIhzOhsIRSJRpjR7C4vGx3SwYroABM7jwpjw0aYHLY2FBLb9TATzL1bRAgsBKCBcX0BkMwCNwRBJtNeKAAMzUpZ1XRsxlQvb6XAco7c3mi273R7PUEyz7yxX-FXfdUdCCQ7Yw+GI5Go9FUGi0U1B-GEsPEmtR8kAFgTtOTGasNk2LPTzCzXNOF2u+Ylhel71LIIVf2VwLE1aQkJZDd1zYNUCN3B4pqAA).

Comment: Great! Awesome! Works perfectly! Thanks heaps! I just don't understand what is the `[keyof T]` at the end of `GenerateCombos` doing there?

Comment: Also, if I want to have a factory function that returns a `Mapper`, how would you define the function signature? e.g. newMapper(key: keyof T, func: (value: string) => T[K]): Mapper { return ({key, func});], and still have the enforcement of the types on the parameters?