# Infer type of property based on a given key of an object, through a generic container

Tags: typescript, types

I want to infer the type of a property, mapping from a given key, on an object like:

```
type MyType = {
    foo: string;
    baz: number;
}

const value: MyType = {
    foo: "fooooo yeah",
    baz: 22222
};

const inferred = value['foo']  // string, OK!
```

But when wrapping this in a generic container, I'm stuck with this:

```
type GetValueByKey<T> = (key: keyof T) => T[keyof T];

type MyContainer<T> = {
    hidden: T,
    getHiddenByKey: GetValueByKey<T>
}

function createGenericContainer<T>(hidden: T): MyContainer<T> {
    return { 
        hidden,
        getHiddenByKey: (key: keyof T) => {
            return hidden[key];
        }
    }
};

const container = createGenericContainer<MyType>({
    foo: "fooooo yeah",
    baz: 22222
});

const containerInferred = container.getHiddenByKey('baz'); // string | number, BAD!
```

[This issue seems very close, or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72242484/typescript-enforcing-property-type-based-on-another-property-value-which-is-a-k). Using the approach from those answers, I get this:

```
type MyContainerCombo<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    hidden: T;
    getHiddenByKey: (e: K) => T[K];
  };
}[keyof T]

function createGenericContainerCombo<T>(hidden: T): MyContainerCombo<T> {
    return {
        hidden,
        getHiddenByKey: (key: keyof T) => {
            return hidden[key];
        }
    }
}

const containerCombo = createGenericContainer<MyType>({
    foo: "fooooo yeah",
    baz: 22222
});

const containerComboInferred = containerCombo.getHiddenByKey('baz') // string | number, BAD!
```

How can I make sure that the type of my inferred value is the EXACT type of the property mapping from given key?

[See the issue in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBVDtUAAWTw+1AAF5QABvRQlErJeDwfJXVCUTjMADcrLZ0gYAC9uZx2IhpN8hQBfYIITiCGg6BjQdiQbk0umMllsnGc7kAIg5nM5oDwHkwJt4wpKooloAATG63Yp5ULFMrVSJOEinK5GerNZAANoAcnNkYAuiUVKq+cx+AB5ADSAEJyZSAOKQVAANQ1WoAQnh05A8AAeHAAPgZoAAFPEq9zW4ZUjgAJQMhs4cMdok4WPeilEal4ADCjVQDAy31rDf1DtAam43BR3Jw9sNzALAAkKBuUeXK3hufmiyXIGeq0vPcFklxYPVGiZJgp85xvuoZ6cFzIJcm3XTdOG3bsdWnWd5x-ID62ZVcnFQfEvCZUBV0NUCUV3Q02X3VAjxPTg7wvZsO3bKth17ekGwNPCGOQ1C12PMDByrUdMLZRVDUVL0lUaP1lTnQDG3IDwvxRX9YH-ES4OrXV2jrJt6PZY1QDNC1LWtBhbVwx1xW5d0PXlbtvV9GhhNg74AEkA2+IMxJgwCAgIoiwNIptIydSMzNARNeWGUAAB9+mlWUyH4UsKgAEWzRRxxQGlZOssgZxleAl0bejw3Tf1QCHLtY25VSWOI7chT3Q9WNPCs22bbVQHTGj+1yziSn4+V2M7bxYyfF83y8cS6kgb9pJSwD0uBYDsPA7xIMnCa4KmzKENKpiyDQriSlm-S8LcmqSLqsiW3qwr5r7RCGMYgtmNm7r2uunjuMfH1BMs5zlqQYExM-UapMoGTPsXRSiGU0rzVNc0LStG07VXJ0jOMz0zIElUPoAr6MrswNHMZKzJu++BXOq4jPO88VfP8sAkyC0KpRlb4otizMgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a second generic type, `K extends keyof T`, you can tie things down:

```js
type GetValueByKey<T> = <K extends keyof T>(key: K) => T[K];

type MyContainer<T> = {
    hidden: T,
    getHiddenByKey: GetValueByKey<T>
}

function createGenericContainer<T>(hidden: T): MyContainer<T> {
    return { 
        hidden,
        getHiddenByKey: (key) => {
            return hidden[key];
        }
    }
};

const container = createGenericContainer({
    foo: "fooooo yeah",
    baz: 22222
});

const containerInferred = container.getHiddenByKey('baz');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwDUCGAbArhAQiA0hEAPACoB8UAvFATlBAB7AQB2AJgM5QDW+A9gGZRSACm4gAXFBwBKCmSIBtHAF0A3ACg1oSFACyIAMI8mwJAEsmEAE7EylAN5qoTqAAtTLFswlEANI+cA5vAAEu6eTNh44rDwyOhYuPg2agC+GnxoTADGwKZGUFmWEEiMcBaWplmGxmblNkJuHl6CUhJ61SbmVjZQDs5QRcBolky9UP79To3hfpOBIWHMkfgSIvgy5GR9c5ODw6PTzPKiqhOTaf1pKepqWUZswAVGneUUBUUlEGVWlR21VkJtk4+DweBIAEQg0GgqAgYoucGzZwAIyQAC8JAAmbHY1JSG53JgPJ41LqWACSTD4ViKLDehJeVgAdEFgKEmhFEiAhAByVFonn4tQAemF-QAegB+IA)